# Error al abrir una web desde java

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo abrir una pagina web desde java?

Estoy desarrollando un programa en java en el que requiero abrir el navegador y mostrar una pagina, las url para dichas paginas las tengo guardadas ya en una base de datos pero tengo dos problemas:

primero si intento abrir una ruta que tenga de símbolos '' o '/' me marca un error de caracteres inválidos

> "java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 6: https:\stackoverflow.com"

usé la función `replaceAll()` para cambiar caracteres especiales por "%2F" ya que según encontré eso es el código hexadecimal para las diagonales lo cual resolvió el primer error pero cuando se abre el navegador muestra el home de google y no el url deseado.

MIS PREGUNTS SON:
¿Cómo puedo hacer que en se abra la URL deseada y no la pagina de home del navegador?

o

¿Existe otra forma de solucionar el error de los caracteres invalidos?

adjunto mi codigo:

```
 public void abrirDocumento(File rutaArchivo) throws URISyntaxException{
         try{ 
         //convierto la ruta en un string para poder comprobar si la ruta es una pagina web o un archivo local    
      String comprobarURL= rutaArchivo.toString();
      System.out.println("la ruta es: "+comprobarURL);
             
      String []parts=comprobarURL.split(":");

      String parte1=parts[0];
      System.out.println("String para saber si la ruta es web o archivo local = "+parte1);
      if(parte1.equals("https")){
          
        //en caso de que sea una web abre el navegador y ve a la url
          if(java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
              java.awt.Desktop desktop= java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
              if(desktop.isSupported(java.awt.Desktop.Action.BROWSE)){
                  System.out.println("abriendo el navegador");
                    //convierto la ruta de el archivo a una variable de tipo URI para poder llamar al metodo browse    
                    java.net.URI url=new java.net.URI(rutaArchivo.toString());
                    //abro el navegador con la ruta de la pagina requerida
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
                  //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
              }
          }
          
          
            
               
      }else{
          //en caso de que no sea una pagina web y sea un archivo local abre el archivo local
          Desktop.getDesktop().open(rutaArchivo);
      }
  
   }catch(IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Podrías por favor incluir en tu pregunta el contenido del archivo?

Comment: Más que el contenido, dónde se define la URL

Comment: Tratas de abrir un archivo local pero tienes definida como ruta "https:\stackoverflow.com" ? me parece que esta confundiendo el archivo local con una url,. agrega como obtienes rutaArchivo.

Comment: el programa está pensado para abrir dos tipos de archivos, locales y paginas web la separación está en el if y cuando son url sencillas como www.google.com o www.youtube.com si funciona pero cuando se pone la url a un video por ejemplo no carga la misma

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de esto que comentas "cuando se pone la url a un video por ejemplo no carga la misma"? , el if solo define si estas usando "https"

Answer (score 1):

encontré el error, el problema estaba en que al hacer la conversión a File desde string se eliminaban los caracteres "//" del url y por eso al abrir el navegador no se localizaba ninguna pagina o url valido, la solución fue mandar el link como string y hacer la conversión a Url o File directo sobre la línea de código de apertura mi método quedó así

```
    public void abrirDocumento(String rutaArchivo) throws URISyntaxException{
        
        System.out.println("la ruta recibida es: "+rutaArchivo);
        
         try{ 
         //convierto la ruta en un string para poder comprobar si la ruta es una pagina web o un archivo local    
      String comprobarURL= rutaArchivo.toString();
      System.out.println("la ruta es despues de su conversion a string: "+comprobarURL);
             
      String []parts=comprobarURL.split(":");

      String parte1=parts[0];
      System.out.println("String para saber si la ruta es web o archivo local = "+parte1);
      if(parte1.equals("https")){
          
        //en caso de que sea una web abre el navegador y ve a la url
          if(java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
              java.awt.Desktop desktop= java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
              if(desktop.isSupported(java.awt.Desktop.Action.BROWSE)){
                  System.out.println("abriendo el navegador");
                    //convierto la ruta de el archivo a una variable de tipo URI para poder llamar al metodo browse    
                    java.net.URI url=new java.net.URI(rutaArchivo.toString());
                    //abro el navegador con la ruta de la pagina requerida
                   Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
                //  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
              }
          }     
            
               
      }else{
          //en caso de que no sea una pagina web y sea un archivo local abre el archivo local
          //convierto la dirección del archivo de String a path
          File path=new File(rutaArchivo);
          Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
      }
  
   }catch(IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```